# Unclassifiable statement and other errors in an IF in Fortran

Tags: if-statement, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I have the code:

```
   if i < n then
        x = topsep(1)
        y = topsep(2)
        realvor(n,1) = x + dx
        realvor(n,2) = x + dy   
        imvor(n,1) = (realvor(n,1)*(a**2))/((realvor(n,1))**2+(realvor(n,2))**2)
        imvor(n,2) = (realvor(n,2)*(a**2))/((realvor(n,1))**2+(realvor(n,2))**2)
        tf = .TRUE.
    else 
        x = botsep(1)
        y = botsep(2)
        realvor(n,1) = x + dx
        realvor(n,2) = y - dy
        imvor(n,1) = (realvor(n,1)*(a**2))/((realvor(n,1))**2+(realvor(n,2))**2)
        imvor(n,2) = (realvor(n,2)*(a**2))/((realvor(n,1))**2+(realvor(n,2))**2)
        tf = .FALSE.
    endif
```

Both `i` and `n` are defined as integers and I am inside a do loop for `n = 1,100`. This throws up the following errors:

> Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1) at the 'if i< n then' 
>   Error: Unexpected ELSE statement at (1) at the 'else' 
>   Error: Expecting END DO statement at (1) at the 'endif'

I can't see where these errors are coming from, no matter how I write the if statement (`.NE.` etc.) it seems to throw up the same things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the parenthesis! According to the Fortran standard (2008, ch. 8.1.7.4), the `if` statement should read

```
if ( i < n ) then
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I hadn't realised the spaces before i and after n were  so important.

Comment: The spaces are irrelevant, the brackets matter!

Comment: Yep, my bad, having to get used to reading the errors in terminal!