# Fortran if displays all and not selected

Tags: fortran

Good evening! I'm trying to create a virtual timeline in fortran with Force 2.0
I want to do an if with accept the "a" value, that is the year, and with the if you display the facts that happened that year
I wrote this code:

```
  program Calc
  real :: a
  print *, "Inserisci la data"
  print *, "Type the first number: "
  read *, a
  if a = 1900
  print *, "London arrives to 4 milion inhabitants"
  if a = 1901
  print *, "First trans-oceanic radio transmission"
  read *
  end program Calc
```

but every input I insert it displays all the outputs, not the selected ones.
For example, if I input "1900" it displays both the 1900 and the 1901 facts", but it is not what I wanted. You know what can I do? Thxxx

Comment: Add `implicit none` as the second line to see your mistake.  This isn't how `if` statements work.  In fixed form source the statement `if a = 1900` assigns the value 1900 to variable `ifa`.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28781861/3157076) as an example.  `if (a==1900) ...` and so on.

Comment: adding the double equals and the brackets it says this: C:\Users\Giulio\Desktop\~VTM.f:6.72:

      if (a==1900)                                                      
                                                                        1
Error: Cannot assign to a named constant at (1)
C:\Users\Giulio\Desktop\~VTM.f:8.72:

Comment: I think in your case the [select case](https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap03/select.html) construct would be neater.

Comment: that document is really complicated! Could you give me an example with my variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments to your question, the `select case` construct might be neater in your case:

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer:: year

    write(*,*) "Type the first number: "
    read(*,*) year

    select case(year)
        case(:1899)
            write(*,*) "I guess something happened before 1900"
        case(1900)
            write(*,*) "I am sure at least one cat was born in 1900"
        case(1901:1905)
            write(*,*) "I am sure something happened between 1901 and 1905"
        case(1906:)
            write(*,*) "Everything past 1906"
        case default
            write(*,*) "default case"
    end select

    read(*,*)
end program test
```

[Here is an explanation with flowchart](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fortran/select_case_construct.htm). Note that I have changed the type of the year to an integer.